# Access another SQL Server through stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I want to access another SQL Server to import and update data of that server's database through a stored procedure.

For that I created linked server using `sp_addlinkedserver`.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'LINKEDSERVER'
    ,@srvproduct=N''
    ,@provider=N'SQLOLEDB'
    ,@datasrc=N'[DB-Instance.cuprxxxlj.ap-xxxxxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com]';
```

Then try to access by SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE]
```

And getting errors like

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
>
> Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

I had created database instance on amazon server and another is also on the amazon server and both are publicly accessible but don't know why I'm getting `Server is not found or not accessible`. Am I missing any server site setting or something else?

Please guide me if I am going in wrong direction.

Comment: Is your Amazon Sql Server open to the whole world?  Because if not, then you need to configure some login settings into your linked server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was an instance, I had created "Amazon RDS for SQL Server" which is currently not supporting to "Linked servers".

So I create a new AWS EC2 instance for Windows Server 2012 R2 and then I create Linked servers in it and tried to assess remotely. Now its working fine as I wanted.

Here is detailed [document](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/running-sql-server-linked-servers-on-aws/) to Running SQL Server Linked Servers on AWS

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing the timeout settings?

```
sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 0 
go 
reconfigure with override 
go
```

Answer (score 0):

This article explains in detail how to link one AWS Sql Server to another (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/running-sql-server-linked-servers-on-aws/).  I am not certain what is wrong in your case, but this has a lot of steps that I do not see in your description.

And the one thing that does jump out at me is that you haven't configured any login security/access control.  So unless the target server is open to the world, I would guess that you have to add that as a minimum.

Comment: I had configured user using " EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LINKEDSERVER',@useself=N'False',@locallogin='USER',@rmtuser='USER',@rmtpassword='PASSWORD' " script

Comment: If that's a valid login and it still doesn't work, then I'd recommend starting over and following the steps in the article.  Oops, I just noticed that I never posted the article, my bad ...

Comment: OK, I have added the link.